# Push and load image in viewcontroller from webview

Tags: ios, image, webview

I have a webView which handles extensions. One portion is image file extensions. So far I am able to push it to a new view controller, however the image isn't passed and loading into the new view. I figure I'm making a noobish mistake, just need a little guidance.

Here is the code handling and pushing the view controller.

```
        //Image file links
        NSURL *imageURl = [request URL];
        NSString *imageFileExtension = [imageURl pathExtension];

        //Image file extensions
        NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", imageFileExtension);
        if ([imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"png"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpeg"]) {

            //Image manager
            ImageViewController *vc = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];

            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

The controller it's being pushed to is a regular view controller. Not sure if I should make it a image view controller or another webView controller as the image is within a webView already.

I realize if I tap the image it will load since it's in a webView, but we run into problems with bigger images and unable to navigate back to the previous page.

Any assistance is appreciated.

UPDATED 8/19 with code from webView trying to push the image..

```
        //Image file links
        NSURL *imageURl = [request URL];
        NSString *imageFileExtension = [imageURl pathExtension];

        //Image file extensions
        NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", imageFileExtension);
        if ([imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"png"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpeg"]) {

            //Image manager
            ImageViewController *vc = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
            [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

ImageViewController code.

.h

```
@interface ImageViewController : UIViewController{
    UIImageView *imageView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];


    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:30/255.0 green:30/255.0 blue:30/255.0 alpha:1.0];

}

}
```

Comment: Just to circle back to this. I ended up figuring this out. No further assistance is needed at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a couple of problems. First, when you instantiate ImageViewController, you just do an alloc init, so where is its view supposed to come from? This will be a controller with a blank black view. If the controller was made in a xib, you need to use initWithNibName:bundle:, and if you're using a storyboard, you need to use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:. Second, you haven't done anything to pass the image to this new controller. It looks like what you have is the image URL, not the image itself, so you need to pass that. In ImageViewController, you need to create an NSURL property, lets call it receivedImageURL for example, and assign imageURL to that property:

```
   NSURL *imageURl = [request URL];
   NSString *imageFileExtension = [imageURl pathExtension];
   NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", imageFileExtension);
   if ([imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"png"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpeg"]) {
        //Image manager
        ImageViewController *vc = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Your nib name here" bundle:nil];
        //ImageViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your identifier here"];
        vc.receivedImageURL = imageURL
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
   }
```

Comment: I'm doing this all programmatically, so not using xibs or storyboards. But this is the issue at hand, it's not passing the image to the view controller. The VC shows but with a obvious blank view.

Comment: @ChrisOSX, are you creating a view for the controller in code (in loadView)?

Comment: Only thing I'm doing there is, - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:30/255.0 green:30/255.0 blue:30/255.0 alpha:1.0];

}, I don't know how else to create it, I know how to do webViews.

Comment: @ChrisOSX, So, what's not working? Are you getting a view with the color you set? If you want to show an image, you have to add an image view as a subview of self.view.

Comment: Yes it's setting w/e color I choose. How would I do that second part, setting a image view as a subview?

Comment: @ChrisOSX, you alloc initWithFrame: to create one, then do [self.view addSubview:imageView]; assuming that you called the image view imageView when you created it.

Comment: @ChrisOSX, You never instantiated the image view. What you're doing with the frame is overly complex -- you set the frame, then set the center (unnecessary since you're making it the same size as self.view), and then you set the frame again. Why?

Comment: I took that frame code from the webview I'm using to try and get it to work, it's obviously not correct. How would I initiate the image view?

Comment: @ChrisOSX, really? If you don't know how to instantiate a view, you  really need to hit the books. This is really basic stuff. And, anyway, I did tell you how to do that -- you use alloc initWithFrame:

Comment: Yes really, and seeing how this question is regarding 2 separate view controllers, you weren't specific on which I should initWithFrame on. But carry on, don't feel obligated to post, I realize this is basic stuff that I am clearly overlooking. Thank you for your time.